# I posted a war program in websphere, but the startup failed

Tags: websphere

```
   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
        at com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:32)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:353)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:483)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.as.j(as.java:170)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.as.b(as.java:286)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:424)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.as.unwrap(as.java:528)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:5)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1087)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInbound(SSLConnectionLink.java:617)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.ready(SSLConnectionLink.java:346)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)`enter code here`
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

I posted a war program in websphere, but the startup failed,
Seen from the log is due to the inability to initialize the SSL connection

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything about startup, but the exception means a client tried to connect to your server over HTTPS but didn't trust your certificate.  If your server uses self-signed or cell-administered certificates, clients will invariable warn/reject them.  Consider a proxy server if you don't want to use real trusted certificates in each application server JVM.